# How do I animate an element to swing in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-animations

Since I saw [the Treahouse website](http://teamtreehouse.com/) and the sign effect swinging in the tree, I have been trying to reproduce it.

```
.box{
    width:50px; height:50px;
    background: blue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
    margin:100px;
    float: left;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
}
```

But it won’t swing.

Here’s [a demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/4/).

I also tried a modification of that.

```
bod{
  background:blue;
}
.box{
    width:50px; height:50px;
    background: yellow;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red,0 0 25px red inset;
    margin:100px;
    float: left;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    border-radius:50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing {
 from {
   left: -2px;
 }
 to {
   left: 200px;
 }
}
```

But that doesn’t work either. See that [demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/11/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's some JavaScript or jQuery involved here.

Comment: no, there is no javascript involved. But where is your keyframe?

Comment: tried this but no working... http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/11/

Comment: you must set the position of the box to relative or absolute to animate left. Also change the prfix of the keyframe from webkit to moz, then it works out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might want to try using `transform: rotate()` and like in sven's comment change the prefix to "-moz-" not "-webkit-" because you are using mozilla animations.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/14/

```
.box{
    width:50px; height:50px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-animation:swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin:top;
}

@-moz-keyframes swing{
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
```

Also, the reason they have `-moz-transform-origin: center top;` is so it rotates around the top so using left: -2px to left: 200px will not make sense.

EDIT: new jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/20/

Comment: so is not cross css3 browser?

Comment: It is, you probably used firebug or the in browser inspector to view their css? Because you were using firefox you would only have seen the css that applies to mozilla so you only got -moz-animation and -moz-transform-origin. I will update my answer with an example of added functionality to webkit browsers. Do note that if you view the teamtreehouse website in google chrome they are not swinging. This might be because the animation is choppy in a certain browser and the designer decided it was best not to apply the keyframes to webkit browsers or they just forgot.

Answer (score 0):

When I used the above method, It worked fine in all browsers except IE. By using below code, the 'swing' will work in IE10 & IE11. So sad that IE9 couldn't make it ;P

```
.box{
    width:50px; height:50px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-animation:swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin:top;
    -ms-animation:swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -ms-transform-origin:top;
}

@-moz-keyframes swing{
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
@-ms-keyframes swing{
    0%{-ms-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-ms-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-ms-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
```