# Make Swing (or bounce) effect slowdown

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I guess this would apply to swinging, or bouncing. An example on how to make an object swing here in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910372/css3-swing-element-animation), where this code was posted: http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/149/

How would you make the swinging slow down to a stop?

```
.box{
    width:50px; height:50px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-animation:swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin:top;
}

@-moz-keyframes swing{
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
```

I would like to do other 'inertia effects' as well.  I do not mind using JavaScript or JQuery if that's necessary.  I feel like CSS alone or keyframes is not enough for what I want to do.

I'm fine using setInterval and doing something like this:

```
function prepareAnimation()
{
    setInterval(slowAnimation, 200)
}

function slowAnimation()
{
    speed=$(".box").getSpeed(); // how would I write getSpeed?
    if(speed<=0) return;
    speed = speed - .1;
    $(".box").setSpeed(speed); // how would I write setSpeed (degree would be set in here too)?
}
```

I do not know the best way to changing animation properties through script.  Especially when it comes to changing the duration in the middle of an animation, which I'm not sure is possible at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/150/

```
(function swing() {
    var ang  = 20,
        dAng = 1,
        dir  = 1,
        box = document.getElementById("box");

    (function setAng(ang){
        box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
        box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
        dir = -dir;
        if (Math.abs(ang) > 0)
            setTimeout(setAng, 1000, dir * (Math.abs(ang)-dAng));
    })(ang);
})();​
```

CSS

```
.box{
    width:50px; height:150px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin:top;
}
```

You can switch the initial direction by making the initial values of `ang` and `dir` negative. You can make the "swinging" slow more quickly by increasing the value of `dAng`, but it should be a factor of `ang`.

Comment: Here's an example starting from horizontal then winding down: http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/152/

Comment: Thanks so much.  It's a good starting point for me learning more about scripting animation.  It doesn't seem to work in Firefox though.  It works in Chrome.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a list of how the JavaScript syntax works for these style.webkitTransform commands in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/157/ It looks like mozilla wants the first letter capitalized (due to the leading dash -). Webkit will work with webkit or Webkit, so the best practice is to capitalize the first letter.

Comment: Works great.  I think I'll be doing a lot more animation moving forward.  Thanks again.

Comment: How would you get this to only swing on mouseover and not on page load?