# How to give wiggle animation effect with fixed position?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want an element to be animated like a `swaying plant`. I am looking to animate a div in the following manner.

- Fix the bottom
- Move the head back and forth

Looking for full css solution.

[image]

I have tried this,

```
@keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-0.4deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I animate an element to swing in CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910372/how-do-i-animate-an-element-to-swing-in-css3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `transform-origin` property to `bottom`.

```css
.el {
  margin: 30px 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 150px 50px 0 50px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
  animation: wiggle infinite 3s alternate;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

@keyframes wiggle {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  25% {transform: rotate(-3deg);}
  50% {transform: rotate(5deg);}
  75% {transform: rotate(-1deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(2deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```